# including support library in project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library

When i create a new Android project with min sdk as 2.2 in Eclipse , the support libraries are automatically added to `Android Private Libraries`, `Android Dependencies` and `libs`. That's probably because I had setup a support library project(`appcompat_v7`) earlier as per https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html.

[image: package explorer]

So my question is there a better way to include the support libraries in a project rather than have it appear all over the place? Is this the expected way?

Comment: What is your Android SDK Tools version?

Comment: @beworker It's the latest - 23.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest ADT automatically creates a new Android library project called `appcompat_v7` in your workspace. This library project contains all the jar-files needed for supporting older Android version.

When you create a new Android application project, it will automatically receives a new dependency on that library project. It looks there is a small bug in ADT causing `android-support-v4.jar` to be added twice. You can safely remove `android-support-v4.jar` from the `libs` folder, as this jar-file is already available in `appcompat_v7`.

The best practice would be to keep a dependency on `appcompat_v7` and delete duplicated `android-support-v4.jar` file.

Comment: I had manually created the appcompat_v7 project in the earlier ADT bundle. It's good to know that it is created automatically now.